# Multiple one to many association for a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have four models: Interview, Interviewee, Interviewer and InterviewDate.

The relations in terms of rails associations are as follows:

1. An InterviewDate can have many Interviews (One to Many)
2. An Interviewee can have many Interviews (One to Many)
3. An Interviewer can have many Interviews and an Interview can have
   many Interviewers (Many to Many)

So, as you can see there are three incoming "Many" relations on the **Interview** model. How should the routing be done in rails given that I need to perform following tasks in the view ?

1. List all Interviews grouped by InterviewDate
2. Form for creation of an Interview (which would also include saving
       fields from other 3 tables into the database).

Comment: What speaks against usual `/interviews/` and `/interviews/new`?

Comment: Does InterviewDate really need to be a separate model? It's something I'd model as just another attribute of Interview, and to get all interviews on a given date you would just search by date.

Comment: I am just creating another model for InterviewDate as I want to reduce the data redundancy that would be caused when it is included in the Interview Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be listing interviews then you have to start with something like this:

```
resources :interviews
```

Since you will have many to many associations is possible you will need to use something like this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Also check this other resource because you will have to work with nested forms/attributes: https://www.sitepoint.com/master-many-to-many-associations-with-activerecord/

Comment: Thanks ! Another doubt I had is can I have this direct route for interviews along with route like /interviewee/1/interviews or /interviewer/1/interviews.

Comment: You will have to work with nested resources, something like this:

 `resources :interviews do
    resources :interviewee
end`

`resources :interviews do
    resources :interviewer
end`

Comment: Would I be able to use a single "Interview" controller to save the nested attributes for interviewer and interviewee ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're listing **Interviews**, your route should be the default `/interviews/`:

```
resources :interviews
```

And your create form should make use of [ActiveRecord's Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Depending on the complexity of your form you may want to use the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), but it isn't required.